# Convert a matrix A in a sparse formats CSR, COO, etc

Tags: c, sparse-matrix, cusp-library

I have a little problem, I would like to convert a matrix 10*10 in a [**CSR**](http://docs.cusp-library.googlecode.com/hg/classcusp_1_1csr__matrix.html#_details) or [**COO**](http://docs.cusp-library.googlecode.com/hg/classcusp_1_1coo__matrix.html#_details) sparse matrix/format. The matrix is:

```
 1.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
-0.45  0.10 -0.45  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
 0.00 -0.45  0.10 -0.45  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
 0.00  0.00 -0.45  0.10 -0.45  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
 0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.45  0.10 -0.45  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
 0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.45  0.10 -0.45  0.00  0.00  0.00
 0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.45  0.10 -0.45  0.00  0.00
 0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.45  0.10 -0.45  0.00
 0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 -0.45  0.10 -0.45
 0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  1.00
```

I am using the ["CUSP"](http://code.google.com/p/cusp-library/) functions but it did not work, once tha matrix **A** I would like just to convert in other format. *Can you help me?*

Well I would like also to use this matrix to solve the system **Ax=b**, using [bicgstab](http://docs.cusp-library.googlecode.com/hg/group__krylov__methods.html):

```
b=
   0.00000
   0.34202
   0.64279
   0.86603
   0.98481
   0.98481
   0.86603
   0.64279
   0.34202
   0.00000
```

My code for this is:

```
int n = 10, r;

cusp::coo_matrix<int,float,cusp::device_memory> A(n, n, 3*n - 4);
cusp::array1d<float, cusp::device_memory> x(A.num_rows, 0);
cusp::array1d<float, cusp::device_memory> b(A.num_rows, 1);

   b[0]=0.00000;
   b[1]=0.34202;
   b[2]=0.64279;
   b[3]=0.86603;
   b[4]=0.98481;
   b[5]=0.98481;
   b[6]=0.86603;
   b[7]=0.64279;
   b[8]=0.34202;
   b[9]=0.00000;

i=0;
// row 0
A.row_indices[i] = 0.0;
A.column_indices[i] = 0.0;
A.values[i] = 1.00;

++i;
// rows 1 through n - 2
for (r = 1; r != n - 1; ++r) {
  A.row_indices[i] = r;
  A.column_indices[i] = r - 1;
  A.values[i] = -0.45;
  ++i;
  A.row_indices[i] = r;
  A.column_indices[i] = r;
  A.values[i] = 0.10;
  ++i;
  A.row_indices[i] = r;
  A.column_indices[i] = r + 1;
  A.values[i] = -0.45;
  ++i;
}
// row n - 1
A.row_indices[i] = n - 1;
A.column_indices[i] = n - 1;
A.values[i] = 1.00;
++i;

// set stopping criteria:
//  iteration_limit    = 100
//  relative_tolerance = 1e-3
    cusp::verbose_monitor<ValueType> monitor(b, 100, 1e-3);

// set preconditioner (identity)
cusp::identity_operator<ValueType, MemorySpace> M(A.num_rows, A.num_rows);

// solve the linear system A x = b
cusp::krylov::bicgstab(A, x, b, monitor, M);

cusp::print(x);
```

The result using Octave should be something similar to:

```
   0.00000
   0.32441
   0.60970
   0.82144
   0.93411
   0.93411
   0.82144
   0.60970
   0.32441
   0.00000
```

But is also with negative numbers, so **WRONG**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For COO, you have to set three array elements for each entry: the row and column indices as well as the value. You can create a matrix like the one you describe using code like this for [COO](https://github.com/cusplibrary/cusplibrary/blob/develop/examples/MatrixFormats/coo.cu):

```
int n = 10, i = 0, r;
cusp::csr_matrix<int,float,cusp::host_memory> A(n, n, 3*n - 4);
// row 0
A.row_indices[i] = 0;
A.column_indices[i] = 0;
A.values[i] = 1.00;
++i;
// rows 1 through n - 2
for (r = 1; r != n - 1; ++r) {
  A.row_indices[i] = r;
  A.column_indices[i] = r - 1;
  A.values[i] = -0.45;
  ++i;
  A.row_indices[i] = r;
  A.column_indices[i] = r;
  A.values[i] = 0.10;
  ++i;
  A.row_indices[i] = r;
  A.column_indices[i] = r + 1;
  A.values[i] = -0.45;
  ++i;
}
// row n - 1
A.row_indices[i] = n - 1;
A.column_indices[i] = n - 1;
A.values[i] = 1.00;
++i;
```

For CSR you have to specify a column and a value for every entry, and also the index of the first entry for every row including a one-past-the-end index for the one-past-the-end row. A similar piece of code for [CSR](https://github.com/cusplibrary/cusplibrary/blob/develop/examples/MatrixFormats/csr.cu):

```
int n = 10, i = 0, r = 0;
cusp::csr_matrix<int,float,cusp::host_memory> A(n, n, 3*n - 4);
// row 0
A.row_offsets[r] = i;
A.column_indices[i] = 0;
A.values[i] = 1.00;
++i;
// rows 1 through n - 2
for (++r; r != n - 1; ++r) {
  A.row_offsets[r] = i;
  A.column_indices[i] = r - 1;
  A.values[i] = -0.45;
  ++i;
  A.column_indices[i] = r;
  A.values[i] = 0.10;
  ++i;
  A.column_indices[i] = r + 1;
  A.values[i] = -0.45;
  ++i;
}
// row n - 1
A.row_offsets[r] = i;
A.column_indices[i] = r;
A.values[i] = 1.00;
++i;
++r;
A.row_offsets[r] = i;
```

To “convert” the matrix from some other format, you have to let us know in what form your original data is stored. Conversion from a [`cusp::array2d`](http://cusplibrary.github.io/classcusp_1_1array2d.html) should work by simply passing that array to the constructor. In general, creating the matrix in sparse format in the first place like the code above does will provide better scalability.

Also note that your example matrix is arranged in diagonal bands, so [`cusp::dia_matrix`](http://cusplibrary.github.io/classcusp_1_1dia__matrix.html) would be better suited, both in terms of easy encoding and in terms of better performance. To create such a tridiagonal matrix, you can use the following code:

```
int n = 10, r = 0;
cusp::dia_matrix<int,float,cusp::host_memory> A(n, n, 3*n - 4, 3);
A.diagonal_offsets[0] = -1;
A.diagonal_offsets[1] = 0;
A.diagonal_offsets[2] = 1;
// row 0
A.values(r,0) = A.values(r,2) = 0.00;
A.values(r,1) = 1.00;
// rows 1 through n - 2
for (++r; r != n - 1; ++r) {
  A.values(r,0) = A.values(r,2) = -0.45;
  A.values(r,1) = 0.10;
}
// row n - 1
A.values(r,0) = A.values(r,2) = 0.00;
A.values(r,1) = 1.00;
```

About this linear equation you try to solve: could it be that octave is operating on a different matrix than the one you pasted into your question? Because with [sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) I get negative numbers in the result as well:

```py
n = 10
d = dict()
d[(0,0)] = d[(n-1, n-1)] = 1
for r in range(1, n-1):
    d[(r, r-1)] = d[(r, r+1)] = -45/100
    d[(r,r)] = 1/10
A = matrix(RDF, n, n, d)
b = vector(RDF, [
   0.00000,
   0.34202,
   0.64279,
   0.86603,
   0.98481,
   0.98481,
   0.86603,
   0.64279,
   0.34202,
   0.00000,
   ])
for i in A.solve_right(b):
    print('{:+.5f}'.format(float(i)))
```

gives the following vector *x*:

```
+0.00000
-0.45865
-0.86197
-1.16132
-1.32062
-1.32062
-1.16132
-0.86197
-0.45865
+0.00000
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the quick help. I love this page so much.

Comment: I \have another question, but I would not like to open a new topic. What happens if with the that matrix "A" in COO format I wanto to solve an equation systems Ax=b using **cusp::krylov::bicgstab(A, x, b, monitor, M);**   with
  **b= [ 0.00000
   0.34202
   0.64279
   0.86603
   0.98481
   0.98481
   0.86603
   0.64279
   0.34202
   0.00000]**

Comment: @Ivan, in general there should be *one* post per question, so if a new question arises, a new post would be appropiate. You can edit your existing posts or add comments in order to create links between related posts. I've updated my answer in response to your altered question this once.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will verify first the code in octave, but I am pretty sure the result must be positive and I little less than the original **b**. Soon I will post the new question.

Comment: ROFL, man you was right, a little problem with the matrix **A**, the central value must be 1.9 so the Ax=b is solved with the **CUSP**, Now CUBLAS is the second strike. Thk so much.